# Replace specific words amongst page content with value javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace the word `hello` anywhere on the page with the word `hi` using Javascript. I created the script below however it isn't working how anticipated, is there something that I can do  to achieve the outcome desired.

```
function(data) {
            var newdata = data.replace("hello", "hi");
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ncveq90/)

Comment: data.replace(/hello/g, "hi");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, although might be overkill using regular expressions:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/hello/g, "hi")
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ncveq90/1/)

Comment: would using document.body.innerHTml.replace be the best way to do this if I had 200 of these one after another, replacing alot of words on the a page?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best way. I know there are many ways to do this that get more complex. But I tested it in jsfiddle with 200 instances of 'hello' and it changed them all to 'hi' with no issues. Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you are only replacing the first occurence.

Below the JavaScript documentation about replace:

> Note: If you are replacing a value (and not a regular expression),
>   only the first instance of the value will be replaced. **To replace all
>   occurrences of a specified value, use the global (g) modifier**.

You have to use the global modifier as below

```
function(data) {
             var newdata = data.replace(/hello/g,"hi");
}
```

Comment: I updated the fiddle using your code however it's not changed anything. https://jsfiddle.net/3ncveq90/3/ fiddle link

Comment: The replaced content is now in the variable _newdata_ you have to use it to do whatever you want. In the fiddle example you gave me you do nothing with it.